# Why does this collision code not work? (love2d)

Tags: lua, collision, love2d

```
function love.collide ()
  if x < 0 then
    x = 0
  end

  if x < love.graphics.getWidth () - Dolphin:getWidth () then
  x = love.graphics.getWidth () - Dolphin:getWidth ()
  end

end
```

I'm trying to make an x coordinate collision and I have already defined x previously. There is no error but the collision fails to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `x > love.graphic.getWidth() - Dolphin:getWidth()`. Because otherwise your `Dolphin` should always be stuck at the right-hand boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to detect the collision between your object (`Dolphin`) and the boundary of the screen, but you are not comparing the position of the object (which changes); instead you compare the width of the object, which probably doesn't change.

Comment: When I use getWidth, I'm getting the width of my window size not the width of the object. However, I did get this to work simply by changing it to function love.update